# How can I submit an email form on my site using html only? (Without PHP)

Tags: html, css

How can I submit an email form on my site using html only? (Without PHP)
If it's with a third party I want that after sending the user will not be redirected to the address of the server sending emails

Comment: Questions seeking recommendations of products / services (such as third party form handlers) are explicitly off-topic here.

Comment: JS ( axios frontend or ajax calls, or node), Python, Ruby, C#, Java...these are the ways

Comment: I'd probably take a look at services like sendgrid. They have rest APIs that you can call from your front end with a single line of JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

That‘s not fully possible; the only way is to let the user send the e-mail. That‘s achievable by using mailto-links like these:

```
<a href="mailto:adress@website.com">Send mail</a>
```

Learn more at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#linking_to_an_email_address

If you want to use a form, try doing it like this:

```
<form action="mailto:adress@website.com" method="GET">
  <input name="subject" type="text">
  <input name="body" type="text">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response,
I do not want to use this way
I want there to be a form on my site that the user fills out and then when you click submit then it will be sent without logging in to gmail

Comment: Sorry to tell you that, but HTML is simply not able to do something like this. There has to be some kind of Backend or API to perform the action.

Comment: So maybe there are third party services?

Comment: Yes, that would he considerable. But when doing this entirely in the front-end, you may open the doors to attackers sending malicious e-mails from your address because they may modify the frontend code

Comment: @tcrvo yes I'm sure there are but none of them allow you to post data without a backend language or JS.

Comment: Twilio (https://www.twilio.com/?locale=en) may be a good option to pick. Still, a server to handle the mail is necessary.

Comment: The courier's code may have an email js